# getting error y.tab.c:(.text+0x543): undefined reference to `pow'

Tags: lex

I    have    written     lex     and    yacc    program    for    calculator. In    yacc      program     I      have     included     `math.h`     for    arithmetic    operations like    sin,    cos,    pow     etc.    for    compilation    i    use    below    steps
lex    calculator.

```
yacc    -d    calculator.y
cc    -c    lex.yy.c    y.tab.c
cc    lex.yy.c    y.tab.c    -o    a.out
```

It    gives    me    this error:

```
y.tab.c:undefined    reference    to    'pow'
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `-lm` to the 2nd `cc` command-line:

```
cc lex.yy.c y.tab.c -o a.out -lm
```

The `pow` function is defined in the library named `m` (which is a shorthand for math), and this library must be linked (`-l`) to the executable so that the function is available at runtime.